# Javascript google maps foreach infowindows

Tags: javascript, google-maps, geolocation, marker, infowindow

Hey someonse knows why i dind't get my address in the content of my infowindows of the markers ?  in my loop before the geocoderstatus i have my address info but after the geocoderstatus.ok i have undefined or only the last address of my array.

```
     function geocodeAddress(resultsMap) {
          //  var address = document.getElementById('address').value;

            var address = ["Brussel","Oostende","Brugge","Gent","Luik"];



            for(var i = 0; i < address.length;i++)
            {
                //new
                var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

              var geooptions = {
                  address: address[i]
              }




                geocoder.geocode(geooptions, function (results, status) {
                    if (status === google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                        //  resultsMap.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location)




                        addMarker(resultsMap,address[i], results[0].geometry.location);




                    } else {
                        alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
                    }
                });
            }

        }

        function addMarker(map,item,location) {

console.log(item);

            var marker= new google.maps.Marker({
                map: map,
                position: location, //results[0].geometry.location,
                title: item
            });

            var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                content: item
            });



            marker.addListener('click', function() {
                infowindow.open(map, marker);
            });

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution it works only with a jquery.each.
Wierd because its just the same as a for loop.

for(var item in address) isn't working either because then i get only the index and not the value.

this fix the issue    $(address).each(function (index,item)